# Grails - Retrieve an object from another tenant

Tags: grails, multi-tenant

I have a system in grails, already running on a server, and we use tenant solutions to distinguish the branches of the corporation, but now I need to recover information from one branch to another.

The point is when I make the following query in my model:

```
def expedition = Expedition.findByCode(row.code)
```

If my expedition was issued by a branch this find does not return anything to me, after all it was thus the initial architecture for the branch offices not to fill information of each other.

Does anyone know how I can do this? it may just be to return that object at that point, or some annotation in the model, but I would not like to remove my multi-tenant structure because I still need to block some information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the methods on the `grails.gorm.multitenancy.Tenants` class to achieve this:

Allow to find across any tenant:

```
def expedition = Tenants.withoutId { Expedition.findByCode(row.code) }
```

Specify a tenant

```
Long otherTenantsId = 2L
def expedition = Tenants.withId(otherTenantsId) { Expedition.findByCode(row.code) }
```

Of course be careful when doing so or trusting user input for a tenant id as it will give access to other users data.

Note there are also `@WithoutTenant` if you'd like to add it to a class/method level.